# Blackberry 10 PhoneGap 2.3.0 java plugin

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, blackberry-10

**I just want to create a Java plugin for BlackBerry 10 PhoneGap 2.3.0 app on mac os x**

I have tried create a PhoneGap 2.3.0 plugin (in Java/jar method) for BlackBerry 10 app on mac os x but the [process mentioned on Phonegap site](http://goo.gl/1MfQl) is too old and not working on mac, they said that there is a folder inside SDKs path ie; "framework/ext/src/org/apache/cordova/" but "src/org/apache/cordova" is not there.

In case if I create "src/org/apache/cordova" and try to create a build with "ant update -D" it failed with an error ie; "Buildfile: build.xml does not exist!"

Answer (score 0):

There is a tricky part in binding the java code, i have got a solution which i have posted here; http://gauravstomar.blogspot.in/2013/01/blackberry-10-qnx-phonegap-plugins.html